# Button becomes disabled after executing command

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Sometimes the button (Done) becomes disabled after the click event.

I also have to click on the form again in order to re-enable the button.

Here is my code:

[image: Button behavior]

**XAML:**

```
<Button
    Grid.Column="1"
    Height="20"
    Margin="10,5"
    Command="{Binding DoneCommand}"
    Content="Done" />
```

**C#:**

```
private readonly RaiseCommand doneCommand;
private readonly BackgroundWorker worker;

private object _currentUserState;
private int _currentProgress;

public RaiseCommand DoneCommand
{
    get { return doneCommand; }
}

public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    doneCommand = new RaiseCommand(o => worker.RunWorkerAsync(), o => !worker.IsBusy);

    worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += DoDoneCommand;
    worker.ProgressChanged += ProgressChanged;
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += RunWorkerCompleted;
    worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
}

private void DoDoneCommand(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("test");
}

private void ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    CurrentUserState = e.UserState;
    CurrentProgress = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

private void RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

**EDIT:**

My command class.

This class is  processing my commands of XAML.

It implements `ICommand` interface.

```
public class RaiseCommand : ICommand
{
    readonly Action<object> _action;
    readonly Func<object, bool> _canExecute;

    public RaiseCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, null) { }

    public RaiseCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute)
    {
        _action = execute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _action(parameter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because your `worker` returns `IsBusy`? you can also try invoking `CommandManager.RequerySuggested` in your `DoDoneCommand()` method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandmanager.requerysuggested(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @zaitsman How can I fixed it? ...that button is always free after closing MessageBox.

Comment: You need to tell WPF about the changed state of your command after it completes work. In MVVM Light, we call `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` for this purpose, but I don't know if you're using that, because `RaiseCommand` is not an MVVM Light thing. We call it a `RelayCommand` here.

Comment: @dotNET I just started learning C #, and so I just do not use any frameworks. I want to study all the C # moments before I'll use the frameworks. Thanks for the answer, and also, please tell me why does the button works at one time and not work on the other? Please look at the picture.

Comment: I'd love to help, but I don't know what `RaiseCommand` is. This is not a built-in C# or WPF thing, so it seems like you're already using some framework. Can you right-click `RaiseCommand` in your code and choose `Go To Definition` command to see where it is defined?

Comment: @dotNET Oh, no, this is self write code. I'm updating post now.

Comment: @dotNET I updated.

Comment: @KirillK: Right, All you need to do is to call `doneCommand.CanExecuteChanged();` in your `RunWorkerCompleted` function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159072/discussion-between-kirill-k-and-dotnet).

Answer (score 1):

You could call the `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()` method in your `RunWorkerCompleted` method to force the `CommandManager` to refresh the state of all commands:

```
private void RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
}
```

Or you could use an `ICommand` implementation that provides a method to raise the `CanExecuteChanged` event, such as for example Prism's [DelegateCommand](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/cec61021115232eb1384b4939c6774485ff97152/Source/Prism/Commands/DelegateCommandBase.cs) or MvvmLight's RelayCommand.